# print lines of tags that have no attribute in xml python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, web-scraping, elementtree

Let's assume that we have xml file:

```
<School Name = "school1">
  <Class Name = "class A">
    <Student Name = "student"/>
    <Student/>
    <!-- -->
  </Class>
</School>
```

And I have a python script that using parsing. I want to print the line of a tag.
For example I want to print lines of tags that have no "Name" attribute.
Is it possible ?
I saw an example with inheritance ElementTree but couldn't understand it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def read_root(root):
  for x in root:
    print(x.lineNum)
    read_root(x)

def main():
  fn = "a.xml"
  try:
    tree = ET.parse(fn)
  except ET.ParseError as e:
    print("\nParse error:", str(e))
    print("while reading: " + fn)
    exit(1)
  root = tree.getroot()
  read_root(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so unclear. Anyways, if you just want to check if the tag has a `Name` attribute and want to print that line number, you can use `etree` from `lxml` as shown below:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('test.xml')

for element in doc.iter():
    # Check if the tag has a "Name" attribute
    if "Name" not in element.attrib:
        print(f"Line {element.sourceline}: {element.tag}"))
```

output:

```
Line 4: Student
Line 5: <cyfunction Comment at 0x13b8e6dc0>
```

Comment: I want to print the line number. I wrote it too.  Do you know how to do it ? @JayPeerachai

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check @Alex. You need to use `lxml.etree` instead, it offers `sourceline`.

Comment: @Alex XML is not about lines .. its about elements.

Comment: Why is printing comments ? it should be ignored. @JayPeerachai

Comment: How difficult? Simply google it, you should try the rest by yourself. Don't treat the site like a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser like `ET.XMLPullParser` what can read `"comment"` and `"process instructions"`, `"namespces"`, `"start"` and `"end"` events.

If your XML file `'comment.xml'` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School Name = "school1">
  <Class Name = "class A">
    <Student Name = "student"/>
    <Student/>
    <!-- Comment xml -->
  </Class>
</School>
```

You can parse to find `TAG's` without the attribute `"Name"` and comments:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start', 'end', "comment", "pi", "start-ns", "end-ns"])

parser = ET.XMLPullParser([ 'start', 'end', 'comment'])
with open('comment.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as xml:
    feedstring = xml.readlines()
    
for line in enumerate(feedstring):
    parser.feed(line[1])

    for event, elem in parser.read_events():
        if elem.get("Name"):
            pass
        else:
            print(f"{line[0]} Event:{event} | {elem.tag}, {elem.text}")
```

Output:

```
4 Event:start | Student, None
4 Event:end | Student, None
5 Event:comment | <function Comment at 0x00000216C4FDA200>,  Comment xml
```

Comment: I don't the line number. @Hermann12

Comment: @Alex, as balderman commented above, xml has no line numbers. An XML "file" is one continuous line that can be pretty printed for us humans to make it more readable.

Comment: @Alex, you ask for the line, not the line number, but anyway I have edit my answer to fullfill your request. Have fun.